# angularJS: where is better to put image upload logic?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For example in two different controllers i have:

```
$scope.photoChanged = function(files) {
  $scope.type = files[0].type.split('/');
  $scope.selectedPhoto = true;
  $scope.accepted_type = /jpeg|png/.test($scope.type);
  if ($scope.accepted_type && files[0].size < 1990000) {
    $scope.files = files;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $scope.AvatarUrl = $scope.user.SmallAvatarUrl;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
  } else {
    $scope.files = undefined;
  }
  $scope.loadingPhoto = false;
};
```

and:

```
$scope.photoChanged = function(files) {
  $scope.type = files[0].type.split('/');
  $scope.selectedPhoto = true;
  $scope.accepted_type = /jpeg|png/.test($scope.type);
  if ($scope.accepted_type && files[0].size < 1990000) {
    $scope.files = files;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      $scope.ArticlePhotoUrl = $scope.user.ArticlePhotoUrl;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
  } else {
    $scope.files = undefined;
  }
  $scope.loadingPhoto = false;
};
```

and now i want to refactor this code...

but i have one question:

where better is to put this logic?

in:

- main parent `app.js`
- controller in service
- in directive

what is more suitable in this case? then i use this image with image crop...

Comment: place it somewhere in factory

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in a plain js file and pass the $scope as the parameter to work on it.

That can be your helper.js to put all common methods.

```
$scope.photoChanged = function(files) {
  uploadFile($scope,files);
};

var uploadFile = function(scope,files){
scope.type = files[0].type.split('/');
  scope.selectedPhoto = true;
  scope.accepted_type = /jpeg|png/.test(scope.type);
  if (scope.accepted_type && files[0].size < 1990000) {
    scope.files = files;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      scope.ArticlePhotoUrl = scope.user.ArticlePhotoUrl;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
  } else {
    scope.files = undefined;
  }
  scope.loadingPhoto = false;
}
```

the uploadfile method can be in a differnt.js file

Comment: No just mention it in you html that will do

Answer (score 0):

I've found a that the most stable pattern in angular is to modularise the function into both a controller and a directive. So that you can re-use them for any image upload.

This is achieved by creating a new folder inside of your main app directory. So in the same directory as app.js you can create a new folder called image upload.

This sort of directory structure.

- /app

  - app.js
  - /imageUpload

    - imageUpload.js
    - imageUpload.html

the imageUpload.html would be your directive and the imageUpload.js your controller.

You can then reference it from you're main controller initialisation in app.js like so

`angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'myApp.imageUpload'
])`

For an example of this you can look at this github repo for a useful tuts tutorial https://github.com/jay3dec/AngularJS_Firebase_Part1/tree/master/app/view1
in essence its giving you two core benefits.

1. The controller for imageUpload is declared once, so that it can be tested and you do not have repeating code. Any specific var you need to pass you can do in the function e.g `function(image, user, article)`
2. the directive that you declare is then reusable and easier to maintain. You can attach advanced functionality to it such as drag and drop and then simply reference the directive each time you have an image upload.

In your case it would be including that directive for both `ArticlePhotoUrl` and `AvatarUrl` rather than writing two separate controllers for each type.

hope that helps.